# TypeError: cannot cast array data from dtype('float64) to dtype('<U32') according to safe rule

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, sigmoid

```
class SigmoidNeuron:
    def __init__(self):
        self.w=None
        self.b=None
    def perceptron(self,x):
        return np.dot(x,self.w.T)+self.b
    def sigmoid(self,x):
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x))
    def grad_w(self,x,y):
        y_pred = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(x))
        return (y_pred-y)*y_pred*(1-y_pred)*x
    def grad_b(self,x,y):
        y_pred = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(x))
        return (y_pred-y)*y_pred*(1-y_pred)
    def fit(self,x,y,epochs=1,learning_rate=1,initialise=True):
        #initialise w,b
        if initialise: 
            self.w=np.random.randn(1,X.shape[1])
            self.b=0

        for i in range(epochs):
            dw=0
            db=0
            for x,y in zip(X,Y):
                dw+=self.grad_w(x,y)
                db+=self.grad_b(x,y)
            self.w -= learning_rate*dw
            self.b -= learning_rate*db
```

```
`
```

I'm running a sigmoid neural network code and I'm getting error while running this class with data

```
X_scaled_train.astype(float)

array([[ 1.29929126, -0.90185206,  0.03173306, ..., -0.14142136,
        -0.15523011,  0.21232515],
       [-1.16225208, -0.86697607,  1.03451971, ..., -0.14142136,
        -0.15523011,  0.21232515],
       [ 1.77523922,  0.65594214,  0.03173306, ..., -0.14142136,
        -0.15523011,  0.21232515],
       ...,
       [ 1.44058831, -0.58796815, -0.66464655, ..., -0.14142136,
        -0.15523011,  0.21232515],
       [-1.42253612,  0.50481285,  1.54984063, ..., -0.14142136,
        -0.15523011,  0.21232515],
       [ 1.06875397,  0.6791928 ,  0.97880934, ..., -0.14142136,
        -0.15523011,  0.21232515]])
```

```
Y_scaled_train.astype(float)
array([[0.68],
       [0.72],
       [0.72],
       [0.6 ],
       [0.8 ],
       [0.64],
       [0.68],
```

These are the data for train set 
while I'm running this line 
sn.fit(X_scaled_train,Y_scaled_train,epochs=10,learning_rate=0.2)
I'm getting that type error
what should I do to remove it

the error shows

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-167-51016d58d1f5> in <module>()
----> 1 sn.fit(X_scaled_train,Y_scaled_train,epochs=10,learning_rate=0.2)

2 frames
<ipython-input-25-2e09637c6d09> in perceptron(self, x)
      4         self.b=None
      5     def perceptron(self,x):
----> 6         return np.dot(x,self.w.T)+self.b
      7     def sigmoid(self,x):
      8         return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-x))

<__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/11549
https://github.com/blue-yonder/tsfresh/issues/485
Do either of these solve your issue?

Comment: there it says the data is string but not mine i checked it

Comment: I linked two separate issues. Try the other.

Comment: is there any other way instead of downgrading pandas version since i'm writing this code in colab

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
np.array(your_list)

your_list.values.astype(np.float)
```

Or:

```
new_list = [float(i) for i in your_list]
```

Or:

For huge arrays, I would strongly recommend you to use numpy:

```
np.array(your_list, dtype=np.float32)
np.array(your_list,dtype=float)
```

You don't have to assign if it's a float:

```
np.array(your_list)
```

Or:

```
new_list = float("{:.1f}".format(float(input())))
list.append(new_list)
```